# Finding the minima of a function in two ways

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, radicals, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I found a simple question:-
Find the minimum value of $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+4$ where $x\in R$

Now,By AM-GM inequality $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\ge2$$$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+4\ge6$$
Thus min. value $=6$

Second solution:-$$({x+\frac{1}{x}})^2\ge0$$$$\Rightarrow x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2\ge 0$$ $$\Rightarrow x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+4\ge2$$ So min. value$=2$

Now answer from the book says min.$=2$
But I find a contradiction in the Second solution.

If min$=2$ $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2=0$$$$\Rightarrow x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=-2$$
Sum of two squares can be negative only if $x^2$ is negative or $x$ is imaginary which is a contradiction to given statement $x\in R$. So answer must be 6.

Am I making a mistake somewhere or am I correct??

Comment: The thing is, $(x+\frac 1x)^2\gt 0$, not $\ge 0$. There exists no $x\in R$ that satisfies the equality

Comment: Didn't they say that $x+1/x\ge2$, which implies $(x+1/x)^2=x^2+1/x^2+2\ge 4$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+4\geq2\sqrt{x^2\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}}+4=6.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1$, which says that $6$ is a minimal value.

Now, about your question.

Indeed, we need to find a minimum  of $$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2,$$
but we can not say, that the minimum is $2$, because $x+\frac{1}{x}\neq0$ for all real $x$.

Id est, the equality in the inequality $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+4\geq2$$
does not occur, but the inequality
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+4\geq2$$ is true.

All this says that the minimum greater than $2$ and indeed, the minimum is $6$.

Comment: Well then the answer given by them in their solution i.e 2 is wrong and 6 is right??

Comment: @sayan Yes of course. Because for $\geq6$ the equality occurs.

Answer (score 0):

with $$f(x)=x^2+x^{-2}+4$$ we get
$$f'(x)=2x-2x^{-3}$$
$$f''(x)=2+6x^{-4}$$
solving $$f'(x)=0$$ we obtain $x=-1$ or $x=1$ with the second derivative test we get that is clearly a minimum.
thus $$f(1)=f(-1)=6$$

Answer (score 0):

By replacing $t=x^2$ we notice that the min of $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ over $R$ is the same as min of $t+\frac{1}{t}$ over positive $t$. The latter min is 2 attained at $t=1$.

Proving that $f(x) \geq a$ does not necessarily mean that $a$ is a minimum. It only means that the min is no less than $a$. Either it is $a$ or some bigger number. That is why there is no contradiction in your estimates. You showed that $f(x)\geq 6$ with some manipulation and used other tools to also show $f(x) \geq 2.$ these together say that the min is $6$ or larger -- and not 2 on earth! Since $6$ is attained at $x=1$ this becomes the min.